# Assigning a select statement inside of a where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'd like to know if it's legal to do this?

```
select coalesce(myField, (select myfield2 from table1))
from table2
```

I've been trying to get this statement to work for hours:

```
 select 
 coalesce( a.TransactionCurrencyId,

            (
            select c.TransactionCurrencyId
            from CRM_accountbase c
            join crm_pricelevelbase a
            on c.defaultpricelevelid=a.pricelevelid
            where a.pricelevelid=(
                            select a.DefaultPriceLevelId 
                            from
                                 (
                                     select a.DefaultPriceLevelId,c.iCompanyId
                                     from crm_accountbase a
                                     join onyx..company C
                                     on c.iCompanyId=a.accountnumber
                                 ) a
                                 where a.iCompanyId=c.iCompanyId
                                 ) 
            ) TransactionCurrencyId
 from mytable a
```

The problem is not with the logic. It is with the syntax.

**Is it OK to have a select statement inside of a coalesce and another select statement inside of a where condition?**

Comment: are you sure the (select myfield2 from table1) returns not more than 1 record at any time for a specified set of table2 row?  use (select TOP 1 c.TransactionCurrencyId) in other words

Comment: What error are you getting?  And, yes, you can have subqueries in a `coalesce()`.  And, I suspect there is a cleaner way of expressing the logic.  Can you provide sample data and desired results?

Comment: The problem is not with the logic. It is with the syntax.

Comment: You seem very sure.  What is the error message?

Comment: The first problem with the syntax is unbalanced parentheses and what looks like a column alias in the middle of a `coalesce()` statement.

Comment: @GordonLinoff can you point out what is the problem is with the syntax?

Comment: You need the closing parenthesis on the coalesce function.  And also to not alias the subquery.

Comment: Your query seems overly complex. Without knowing why you included onyx..company, I'd say you could reduce your subqueries by 1 or 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's ok to have a select inside of coalesce and inside of a where statement (assuming they return only a single row if you're comparing equality).

See my inline comments near the bottom of the code.

Also, it isn't a syntax problem, but it would be a good idea to not alias three different tables as 'a'.

```
select 
 coalesce( a.TransactionCurrencyId,
            (
                 select c.TransactionCurrencyId
                 from CRM_accountbase c
                 join crm_pricelevelbase a
                 on c.defaultpricelevelid=a.pricelevelid
                 where a.pricelevelid=(
                            select a.DefaultPriceLevelId 
                            from
                                 (
                                     select a.DefaultPriceLevelId,c.iCompanyId
                                     from crm_accountbase a
                                     join onyx..company C
                                     on c.iCompanyId=a.accountnumber
                                 ) a 
                              where a.iCompanyId=c.iCompanyId
                              ) 
            ) --TransactionCurrencyId   <--Need to not alias the subquery here
          )  --< Need to add this parenthesis
 from mytable a
```